# unable to save data to text file using php to save in json format

Tags: php, json, file-io

I use this code to insert data to text file  but its give unable to save date 
any help pleas its can post the file .text but no data can be saved
Unable to save data in "dirdata/formdata.txt"

save_json.php

```
<?php
// Append new form data in json string saved in text file
// From: http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/

// path and name of the file
$filetxt = 'dirdata/formdata.txt';

// check if all form data are submited, else output error message
        if(isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['link']) && isset($_POST['pic']) ) {
  // if form fields are empty, outputs message, else, gets their data
        if(empty($_POST['category']) || empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['link']) || empty($_POST['pic'])) {                   
    echo 'All fields are required';
  }
  else {
    // gets and adds form data into an array
    $formdata = array(
      'category'=> (float) $_POST['category'],
          'name'=> (float) $_POST['name'],
          'link'=> (float) $_POST['link'],
          'pic'=> (float) $_POST['pic'],
    );

    // path and name of the file
    $filetxt = 'dirdata/formdata.txt';

    $arr_data = array();        // to store all form data

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
      // gets json-data from file
      $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

      // converts json string into array
      $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $formdata;

    // encodes the array into a string in JSON format (JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - uses whitespace in json-string, for human readable)
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    // saves the json string in "formdata.txt" (in "dirdata" folder)
    // outputs error message if data cannot be saved
    if(file_put_contents('dirdata/formdata.txt',$jsondata)) echo 'Data successfully saved';
    else echo 'Unable to save data in "dirdata/formdata.txt"';
  }
}
else echo 'Form fields not submited';
?>

​
```

index.html

```
<form action="save_json.php" method="post"><br><br><br><br>
<head>
<title>Add iptv channel</title>
</head>
<center><body>
 ADD IPTV CHANNEL
</body></center><br><br>

<center>category: <input type="text" name="category" id="category" SIZE="100" MAXLENGTH="40"/></br>.</center><br>

<center>name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" SIZE="100" MAXLENGTH="40"/></br><br>.</center>

<center>link: <input type="text" name="link" id="link"SIZE="100" MAXLENGTH="40" /></br><br>.</center>

<center>pic: <input type="text" name="pic" id="pic" SIZE="100" MAXLENGTH="40"/></br><br>.</center>

<center><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></center>​
```

Answer (score 0):

file_put_contents requires full server path

```
$filetxt = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dirdata/formdata.txt';
```

Comment: I try with
if(file_put_contents('test/dirdata/formdata.txt',$jsondata))   not success

Comment: was it with success ? unlikely. if you somehow don't want to use my answer, write real path. for windows like `c:\webserver\my\...`, for unix like `/usr/www/public...`

Comment: I use Linux and both file I upload to var/www

Comment: if `/var/www` is www root, then `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` must return `/var/www/` and $filetxt will be `/var/www/dirdata/formdata.txt`

Comment: Suppose,  you use windows and put your server at `c:\web\public`. For example, you have file on www server `/dirdata/formdata.txt`. But its real path `c:\web\public\dirdata\formdata.txt`.  PHP script has global variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to know where www root is placed. And when you used file manipulation function you must say or `c:\web\public\dirdata\formdata.txt` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']./dirdata/formdata.txt`. The last is more suitable.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer?